# moving large PostgreSQL/PostGIS database

Tags: postgresql, migration, postgis

I need to move and upgrade a very large (~320 GB) PostGIS database from *server1* (PostgreSQL 9.1, PostGIS 1.5) to *server2* (PostgreSQL 9.3, PostGIS 2.1).

The upgrade process is [well-documented](http://www.postgis.org/docs/postgis_installation.html#hard_upgrade). The problem is I don't have enough space on *server1* to dump the file there, checksum it, then copy it to *server2* and verify sums. I tried:

- Piping the dump from *server1* to *server2* using `nc`.
- Writing a dump file directly to a *server2* filesystem which is mounted on *server1* using `sshfs`.

Both times the dump file appears to have been corrupted. `pg_restore` broke in different places with errors like this:

`pg_restore: [compress_io] could not uncompress data: incorrect data check`

Can anyone suggest a better way to get this move and upgrade done?

**UPDATE:** Tried NFS (and gave SSHFS another try). It's clear that **these remote filesystems can't reliably transfer this much data**. Blocks are visibly missing from the resulting SQL file, causing syntax errors like this during import:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "8266UPDATE spatial_ref_sys o set auth_name = n.auth_name, auth_srid = n.auth_srid, srtext = n.srtext, proj4text = n.proj4text FROM _pgis_restore_spatial_ref_sys n WHERE o.srid = n.srid;"
```

Comment: The second option seems good but why don't you use NFS? Perhaps there is some small interruption that is not well handled by sshfs. 320Gb is quite a big file.

Comment: Buy a bigger disk? 1Tb costs next to nothing these days.

Comment: Turns out NFS is just as unreliable as SSHFS for transferring this much data. Updating question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend dumping the 9.1 database from your new 9.3 server like this:

```
pg_dump -h remoteserver -U remoteuser remotedbname -Fc -f my_old_server_backup.dump
```

I recommend using the 9.3 `pg_dump` as `pg_dump` is always backwards compatible, but not forward compatible. In other words, the newer `pg_dump` will take care of any syntax changes that the new server requires that the older utility doesn't know about.

Be sure to make sure your `pg_hba.conf` and `listen_addresses` in `postgresql.conf` are set up to allow you to remotely connect and dump appropriately as well.

If you wanted to try a dump and restore in one step, you could try this as well:

```
pg_dump -h remotehost -U remoteuser remotedbname | psql -U localuser localdbname
```

Hope that helps. =)

Comment: The "dump and restore in one step" probably won't work because of differences between the PostGIS versions, but **running the dump remotely from the receiving server and restoring from it worked!** This is clearly better than using network filesystems. Thanks, I now have a functioning database!

Comment: Is that a performative process? It looks to me that will take some days to complete. Then will pgdump create a dump file with ~300GB if I don't use a server to server remote backup?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to move huge Geodatabase, I suggest you another approach:

1. from the new database recreate the original schema from a DDL.
2. create a remote database wrapper and import remote tables into a
   temporary schema (eg. old_schema_temp).
3. move data from remote tables, following your data model structure,
   into your schema
4. delete remote database wrapper